# Is it possible to remove borders a single QWidget around a QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

This is a very simple problem to reproduce. Create a new project with Qt Creator with a `QMainWindow`. Using designer add a single widget (it doesn't matter which one) and then use the right button to set a layout (any layout as with a single widget the results are always the same).

There will be a gray border around the widget. I would like to remove this border so that the widget occupies the entirety of the main window area (which Qt always names `centralWidget`).  Basically the single widget is all I want to see.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Set the layout's [contents margins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) to 0?

Comment: When I do what I've described, even though the widget is "in a layout" there is no layout appearing in QDesigner to set it's margins to zero. So how would I try what you suggested?

Comment: The layout properties are always shown in the widget's properties which contains the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. All you need is setting margins of that `centralWidget` to `0`. (note that you should first set up a layout)

In properties panel set the following properties to `0`.

- `layoutLeftMargin`
- `layoutTopMargin`
- `layoutRightMargin`
- `layoutBottomMargin`

[image]

---

Also note that using a `QWidget` (not `QMainWindow`) as your main app window is perfectly valid, so if your app has only one widget, you won't need a `QMainWindow` at all. It's enough to `show` that widget.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is the right answer but I also wanted to share what I've found out. I basically wanted to create a QGraphcisView that occupies the entire screen. and I thought of the above method, which Hi I'm Frogatto answered. Another way is to create  a simple app with this code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
    view->showFullScreen();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And this .pro file:

```
QT += core gui widgets

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = Test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

This also does what I wanted!. Maybe it can help someone.